# how to add a featured image to a post, with custom post type and custom taxonomies?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a website which allows users to add photographs to their own account.
Users were successfully able to upload photos, by uploading custom posts on a html form and that worked, using set_post_thumbnail to set the featured image.

I have since added custom taxonomies, which allows the users to assign each photo they upload to an album.  However, this has stopped the image from uploading somehow.  The post is being uploaded, into the specified album, but there is no image.  The image does not appear in the media section on the WP back end either.

```html
if ($_POST == true){

  $post = array(
   'comment_status' => 'open',
   'ping_status' => 'closed',
   'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
   'post_status' => 'publish' ,
   'post_title' => $_POST['Title'],
   'post_type' => 'music_review',
   'post_content' => $_POST['Comment']
   
   //inserts new post into 'uploads' database
   );
 $new_post = wp_insert_post( $post );
 require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
 require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
 require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );
  
  
  
  $terms = $_POST['album']; //takes name from 'album' in html
  
  //if checkbox is ticked
  if (isset($_POST['album'])) {   //Username ='". $_GET['user']."'";
    //echo "YES"; 
    
    $assign_to_album = wp_set_object_terms( $new_post, $terms, 'Albums'); 
    
    
   }
   
   
  $attachment_id = media_handle_upload( 'image', $new_post );
  //new dBug($_FILES['image']);
  set_post_thumbnail($new_post, $attachment_id);
  //inserts the image to the post 
  
  
  add_post_meta($new_post, 'Username', $user_data['Username']);
  //adds custom field to the post, assigns username of current
  //logged in user to the custom field
  
  //$assign_to_album = wp_set_object_terms( $new_post, $link[0] . "-" . $link[1], 'Albums'); 
  echo "Your upload has been successful!<br>";
  
  
  }
       ?>

 
     <div id="content">

     <form name="uploadingImage" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]?>" method="post">
         <br>Enter a title for your upload: <input type="text" name="Title"/>
    <br>
    <input type="file" name="image"/>
    Select an album for your upload.  You can choose more than one album.
    <?php  


    // puts albums as checkboxes 
    $albums = get_terms( 'Albums', array('orderby'=> 'count','hide_empty' => 0,) );        
        foreach ($albums as $album)
        {
           // Casts each album(object) to an array
           $albumarray = (array) $album;       
           //sets $albumname as only the album name from each object
           $albumname = ($albumarray['name']);       
           //converts the album name variables into an array
           $albumnames = array($albumname);          
           {
            foreach ($albumnames as $link)
             {         
               // splits each album name into an array, with each item divided by a '-'
              $link = explode("-", $link);          
              if ($user_data['Username'] == $link[0])
              {    //new dBug($link); 
               ?>
               <input type = "checkbox" name='album' value="<?php echo $link[0] . "-" . $link[1]?>" checked><?php echo $link[1]?>
               <br>                 
               <?php                  
              } 
             }  
           }
        }?>
               <input type="submit" value="Submit!" />
               </form>

               <br>


     

     <?php the_content() ?>


     <?php get_footer(); ?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array('supports' => 'thumbnail')
```

Add this to your CPT declaration.